# running x86 program _on_ llvm

Tags: x86, llvm

Is it possible to use llvm to run x86 programs? I.e. I want to use llvm as an x86 simulator to run x86 programs and then instrument the x86 program.

Thanks!

Comment: To quote Charles Babbage, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."

Comment: Great question! I had actually read about LibCPU a couple of weeks ago, but completely forgot about it. This question prompted me to go back and look at it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [LibCPU](http://LibCPU.Org/).

It has [an x86 frontend](http://LibCPU.Org/wiki/index.php/X86) (well, actually only 8086 at the moment, and that is not even complete, but they're working on it), and since it is built on top of LLVM, it obviously also has an x86 backend, thus making it possible to run x86-on-x86 but passing it through LLVM's optimization, instrumentation and analysis stages.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there was a project to use LLVM in qemu. It is also a way of running x86 code via LLVM.

http://code.google.com/p/llvm-qemu/

It was GSoC project, but there is a code in svn and author have  results:

```
regular qemu     llvm-qemu rle,dse,simple regalloc   llvm-qemu full opts
4m35.349s             5m39.697s                        13m50.697s
```

llvm-qemu twice-thrice slower than qemu, but it works.

Comment: Apparently it was conceived as way to optimize qemu.  I would guess, the reason it was abandoned was because of these discouraging results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know libCPU, but there is `libx86`, which does something very similar; if running on an 32-bit x86 processor (but not in 64-bit mode), it runs a virtual 8086 process, if running elsewhere, it tries to emulate the `8086` in software. Pretty cool. Documentation is relatively scarce though.

http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/libx86/